# R Class turning to NULL instead of date

Tags: r, date, dplyr, tidyverse, lubridate

So I have data as follows

```
data <- structure(list(LICENCE_RENEWAL_DATE = c("NA", "NA", "NA", "2022-02-12T07:42:49Z", 
"2022-02-10T13:52:37Z", "NA", "NA", "2022-02-13T16:37:48Z", "NA", 
"NA"), LICENCE_RENEWAL_DATE2 = c("NA", "NA", "NA", "2022-02-12", 
"2022-02-10", "NA", "NA", "2022-02-13", "NA", "NA")), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")
```

I get this by running the following:

```
data <- full_data %>% 
  mutate(LICENCE_RENEWAL_DATE2 = substr(LICENCE_RENEWAL_DATE, 1, 10)) %>% 
  select(LICENCE_RENEWAL_DATE, LICENCE_RENEWAL_DATE2)
```

I thought I could just sandwich the `substr()` with as_date() from `lubridate` but this is not working. The class for `LICENCE_RENEWAL_DATE2` is NULL and I dont know what to make of that. But I would need this to be class = Date.

Comment: `full_data` --> `data`?

Comment: `as.Date()` won't work with `"NA"`, try `NA` instead

Comment: @r2evans there is a large data set(full_date), from this dataset. a new var is created with the mutate()

Comment: So ... your code is starting with data we don't have, producing the data that we see in your first code block? It would be really good to see what the data looked like *before* the mutate/select operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
full_data$LICENCE_RENEWAL_DATE2 <- as.Date(full_data$LICENCE_RENEWAL_DATE2, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
```

It will convert the `LICENCE_RENEWAL_DATE2` column's class to `Date`.

```
> class(full_data$LICENCE_RENEWAL_DATE2)
[1] "Date"
```

Comment: yes it worked! thank u

Answer (score 0):

You can Try below Solution**

```
data <- structure(
list(
LICENCE_RENEWAL_DATE = c(" ", " ", " ", "2022-02-12T07:42:49Z", "2022-02-10T13:52:37Z", 
" ", " ", "2022-02-13T16:37:48Z", " ", " "),
LICENCE_RENEWAL_DATE2 = c(" ", " ", " ", "2022-02-12", "2022-02-10", " ", " ", 
"2022-02-13", " ", " ")),  
row.names = c(NA, 10L),class = "data.frame")
```

Don't involve NA while creating Data

```
full_data <- data %>% 
    mutate(LICENCE_RENEWAL_DATE2 = substr(LICENCE_RENEWAL_DATE, 1, 10)) %>% 
    select(LICENCE_RENEWAL_DATE, LICENCE_RENEWAL_DATE2)
```

Convert Both Columns in DateTime ("POSIXct" "POSIXt") and Date

```
library(anytime)
full_data$LICENCE_RENEWAL_DATE <- anytime(full_data$LICENCE_RENEWAL_DATE)
full_data$LICENCE_RENEWAL_DATE2 <- anydate(full_data$LICENCE_RENEWAL_DATE2)
```

Check Data Types

```
> class(full_data$LICENCE_RENEWAL_DATE) 
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt" 
> class(full_data$LICENCE_RENEWAL_DATE2) 
[1] "Date"
```

I Hope this solution will resolved your issue